# Function in R that changes x's missing values into a degault value

Tags: r, function

here is the task:

"x is a vector of any primitive objects such as numeric, character, logical,
or complex. Create a function that will change x's missing values into a
default value: 0 or numeric,  for character, F for logial, and 0+0i for
complex type"

Here is what I got:

```
x = c(12, "hello", TRUE, 1+2i, NA)
change = function(x) {
for(i in 1:length(x)){
if (NA == is.numeric) {
return(0)
} else if 
(NA == is.character) {
return("")
} else if 
(NA == is.logical) {
return ("F")
} else if 
(NA == is.complex) {
return ("0 + 0i") 
}
}
}
```

I keep on getting error like:

Error in NA == is.numeric :
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong and whether I am approaching the problem from a right direction. Thanks!

Comment: R vectors can only have one data type, so `x` here is coerced to being all character values. You might need `x = list(12, "hello", TRUE, 1+2i, NA)`

Answer (score 0):

As Jon said, R doesn't accept multiple types of values in a single vector and would consider all as character values. So, with the list of your values your code requires correction. Here is the function:

```
x = list(12, "hello", TRUE, 1+2i, NA)

fn<-function(x) {
for(i in 1:length(x)){
if (is.double(x[[i]])) {
 return(x[[i]])
}else if (is.na(x[[i]])) {
 return(0)
} else if (is.character(x[[i]])) {
  return("")
} else if (is.logical(x[[i]])) {
  return("F")
} else if (is.complex(x[[i]])) {
  return("0 + 0i") 
  }
}
}
```

Then apply the function and save new values into a new list:

```
g<-vector('list',length = length(x))

for(i in 1:length(x)){
g[[i]]<-fn(x[[i]])
}
print(g)
```

Comment: thank you. Although, I need to replace a missing value in the list and not just the value mentioned in the IF statement.

I used this:
'''
    x = list(12, "hello", TRUE, 0+1i, NA)
    change = function(c) {
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if (is.numeric(x[[i]])) {
    return (0)
    } else if 
    (is.character(x[[i]])) {
    return ("")
    } else if 
    (is.logical(x[[i]])) {
    return ("F")
    } else if 
    (is.complex(x[[i]])) {
    return ("0 + 0i") 
    }
    }
    }
'''
But then when I input change(15) as an example it just returns 0

Comment: What value are you expecting to return by change(15)?

Comment: I would expect my list then look like
x = list(12, "hello", TRUE, 1+2i, 15)

Comment: In my function 'fn',  you must change return(0) ->return(15). Then you must write fn(NA).

Comment: I think there might be some misunderstanding with my explanation of the task. The idea is to write a code where you have a list with missing values. I need to use a function to be able to insert parameters of the function and if the parameter is numeric, the function has to replace this missing value with 0. If the inputs a character, the function shall replace the missing value with "" etc.

Comment: You do not have any condition for missing value to return in your function (change). Compare my function with yours. Hope it helps

Comment: I have something like that now but it does not change the missing value for some reason
`
change = function(c) {
 x = list(12, "hello", TRUE, 0+1i, NA)
 for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if (i == is.numeric(c)) {
  return(x[[5]][1]==0)
 } else if 
  (i == is.character(c)) {
  return(x[[5]][1]== "")
 } else if 
  (i == is.logical(c)) {
  return(x[[5]][1]== "F")
 } else if 
  (i == is.complex(c)) {
  return(x[[5]][1]== "0 + 0i") 
   }
  }
 }
`

Comment: I have also tried your code and input the parameter (20) but it gave me the error:
Error in change(20) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'